# creating Tag Cloud in Coldfusion OR JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, coldfusion

I need to Create a Tags Cloud but I don't know how. I use Coldfusion on Server.

So will it be better to create with JavaScript Or Coldfusion?

Can I cache the Tags Cloude?

what kind of infos do i need to create this Tag?

Comment: You're not showing any initiative here. It just feels like you're asking a "here do this thing for me" type question. Why don't you try to do it yourself and then ask questions about problems you run into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used this code from Pete Freitag before and it worked great: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/396.cfm

Comment: `Jeffery Zeldman proclaims that tag clouds are the new mullets.` from 2005 nonetheless.

Comment: How is this helpful? The user asked about creating a cloud. Obviously s/he feels it is the UI form they want to use.